# Calculate the values from select option with Javascript and/or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

*Firstly: I know I should provide my solution and explain what's not working. But unfortunately I'm still learning HTML and PHP, so I don't have experience with Javascript. Thought, I hope somebody can help me.*

In my website there's a form. In this form there's this code:

```html
    <select name="size">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Size ↓</option>
     <option value="AAA">AAA (10 €)</option>
     <option value="BBB">BBB (20 €)</option>
     <option value="CCC">CCC (30 €)</option>
     <option value="DDD">DDD (40 €)</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name="discount">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Option ↓</option>
     <option value="Option1">Option 1 (0 %)</option>
     <option value="Option2">Option 2 (-5 %)</option>
     <option value="Option3">Option 3 (-8 %)</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name="method_of_payment">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Method of payment ↓</option>
     <option value="transfer">Transfer (0 % cashback)</option>
     <option value="debit">Debit (-3 % cashback)</option>
    </select>
```

This is like a shop. I want to pre-calculate the final price for the user with Javascript. (I don't want to reload the website. Otherwise I would do it with PHP.) I want to have an output like: `The final price is 18,43 €. You saved 1,57 €`.

The cash back from "method_of_payment" must go on the final price of size and discount. That means for `size = BBB` and `discount = Option2` and `method_of_payment = debit`: `20-(20/100*5)=19 | 19-(19/100*3)=18,43 €`

Another problem is, that I have the values like `AAA` and `Option1` and `transfer` in my database when the form gets submitted. Bus as far as I know Javascript needs the value for calculation in the `value=""` field. Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are storing **actual** values in the value attribute of each option:

```
<select name="size">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Size ↓</option>
    <option value="10">AAA (10 €)</option>
    <option value="20">BBB (20 €)</option>
    <option value="30">CCC (30 €)</option>
    <option value="40">DDD (40 €)</option>
 </select>
```

And with `jQuery` you can do something like the following:

```
var price = $('select[name=size]').val() * ($('select[name=discount]').val() * 1/100) * $('select[name=method_of_payment]').val();
```

If you have an HTML element such as a label, you can display it like this:

```
$('.mylabel').text(price);
```

I gather that you haven't done this before. So to go a step further, you need to think that the calculation needs to be re-run every-time the value of a select changes. So a complete example would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // this will run on every select value change. if you want it to only run for those specific selects, add the same class in all of them and change the selector to $('select.yourclass')
   $('select').on('change', function() {
      $('.mylabel').text($('select[name=size]').val() * ($('select[name=discount]').val() * 1/100) * $('select[name=method_of_payment]').val());
   });

});
```

** EDIT **

A working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2cs8vcLo/

Comment: you can try jQuery function like a $('select ').on("change", function()) use as well as you want :)

Comment: I didn't use jQuery until now, but I just "installed" it. But how can I get an output with your code?

Comment: Still not working. I'm having the following code: https://codeshare.io/ZOuV8. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @David - rather than just copying and pasting my code and expect it to work magically, you should read my answer carefully. How do you expect to calculate `AAA * Option1 * debit` if you don't **attach values** to them???

Comment: also, `$('.mylabel')` selects elements with **class** `mylabel`. you should be looking for `$('#mylabel')` which means element with `id=mylabel`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I updated my code but it's still not working. Can you have a look at it, please? Link:  https://codeshare.io/ZOuV8

Comment: @David - You are still missing quite a lot from my answer. Have a look at this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/2cs8vcLo/

Comment: Working now. Thank you very much. But still a question. When submitting this form, it'll insert the digits in my database because `$_POST`/`$_GET` work with `value=""`. I there a way to take different values for Javascript calculation and PHP $_POST/$_GET?

Comment: add an `<input type="hidden"... />` in your `form`, set it's value using `JavaScript` or `jQuery` and then from the target page, request the value from that element rather than the `select`